# Magento product types

Tags: magento, product, configurable

How do know which product type to use in Magento? Especially, when should I use simple and configurable products?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [wiki page](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product/producttype) describes the different product types.

Answer (score 8):

Get product collection by type :

```
$collectionSimple = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'));
$collectionConfigurable = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'configurable'));
$collectionBundle = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'bundle'));
$collectionGrouped = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'grouped'));
$collectionVirtual = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'virtual'));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have options to select before adding the product to cart, then use **configurable product**. For example, Shoes. In shoes, you have the option to select size.

If you don't have any option to set before adding product to cart, then use **simple product**.